# CanCan authorization fails sometimes for admin but when I refresh it works

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, cancan, cancancan

I am giving to admin user different ability than normal users
When logged in with admin user, sometimes I get not authorized exception on some actions even though it should be authorized and but then when  I refresh the page I am authorized again.

Does anyone has any idea how to solve this issue or what is causing it?

my controller and action:

```
before_action :authorize_vendor

def delivery
  @order = Order.find_by(number: params[:id])
  authorize! vendor_action, @order
end

def vendor_action
  "vendor_#{action}".to_sym
end

def authorize_vendor
  record = if respond_to?(:model_class, true) && model_class
              model_class
            else
              controller_name.to_sym
            end        
  authorize! :vendor, record
  authorize! vendor_action, record
end
```

The below is the ability class code

```
@vendor_ids = vendors.pluck(:id).first
can :vendor, Order, vendor_id: @vendor_ids
can :vendor_delivery, Order, vendor_id: @vendor_ids
```

I'm using rails 5.1.6

Comment: I've thought about this, but for myself, I'm thinking I'd only be guessing based on this much information. Perhaps someone comes along that has had the same problem.

Comment: Please add an example https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @Austio  I have added more details can you please recheck

Comment: MCVE stands for "Minimal, **Complete, Verifiable** Example". Your example is neither complete, nor verifiable. My only guess is that this is the dodgy line: `@vendor_ids = vendors.pluck(:id).first` -- Why is this variable called "ids" if you only want one value? And could that value be changing (i.e. if you add a new vendor to the current user)?

Comment: You didn't actually show what `vendors` is, or what it means in this context, but my guess is that you should just be using `@vendor_ids = vendors.pluck(:id)` here.

Comment: Also, side note -- `cancan(can)` is, in my opinion (and in the opinion of the library's original author!) a bad design. Use `pundit` instead, if possible.

Comment: please add more context. Following your code is not possible to reproduce the issue.  @TomLord, where does Ryan Bates say that?

Comment: @coorasse I can't find a specific discussion thread off hand, but a recurring theme over and over with that project was "this feels really cool for small projects, but as soon as you start applying it to a big/complex application, the `Ability` class grows out of hand". And I've experienced this pain myself, first hand. To be honest, I wish the `cancancan` fork had been marked as "deprecated" on day one, in favour of better design patterns, rather than continuing to push it as one of the best solutions - purely because it was one of the *first* solutions.

Comment: I can suggest you this article then: https://medium.com/@coorasse/cancancan-that-scales-d4e526fced3d. I work with cancancan since many years and I personally never had problems regarding performance or scalability, neither implementing any design pattern since none is defined within the library.